# Wordpress custom mod_rewrite - totalnoob?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to make a custom mod_rewrite rule for my wordpress installation, I've already got a custom rule for my page structure which i would like to preserve.

The new custom rule i'd like to make is whenever there's a get variable like: www.mysite.com/?*profile*=**username**

I want to make it look like: www.mysite.com/**username**

This is my current .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I've looked at php.net and many tutorials about mod rewriting in general and specifically for wordpress, but its all just going straight over my head, I don't understand it.
If anyone could give me some help to get some progress with this i'd really appreciate, i really want to get my head around mod_rewrite.

I'm assuming i need to create a new RewriteRule, but that's as far as i get.

Thanks
Frank

Comment: Do you mean that the URL `mysite.com/username` is `mysite.com/?profile=username` in the backend?

Comment: Yeah your right I was a bit confused, i'm slowly getting my head around this, but that's what i meant to say.

Answer (score 0):

Accomplishing what you want to accomplish is difficult, to say the least. It requires an additional PHP file to parse incoming requests because .htaccess has no way to know if the USERNAME part of the URL is actually a username or not.

The PHP file I mention would load the users table from the database and compare $_GET['profile'] to the entries and, on match, rewrite to /?profile=USERNAME

If there's no match, it simply passes on to index.php.

However, there's a much easier solution here, which preserves a lot of what you want:

```
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+)$ ?profile=$1 [L]
```

What this does is rewrite from /profile/*username* to /?profile=*username*

It's not exactly what you're looking for, but it's much easier to implement. The rule should go directly below `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]` in the .htaccess file.

If you have any questions, I'm more than happy to explain what all is happening here.

Comment: I just put in the update line to my .htaccess but it 404'd when i attempted the url. the /profile/username to /?profile=username is essentially what i'm after.

Comment: That's probably because you're not handling ?profile=$1 properly. You'll need an additional file like I stated and some testing in Wordpress's index.php file.